# How to assign material to solify modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers

With the default sphere and bool tool addon. I applied difference operation on it. And a solidify modifier to the cutter. It has created 3 mesh. Without apply modifiers, I want to apply material on to the solidify.

[image]

[image]

I tried the material index offset. Still the material is not assign to it.

[image]

How to assign material on solidify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we see here is not the rim created by the *Solidify* modifier, but the thickness created by your *Boolean* object (here I made it visible, the solidify just make your object thicker but its rim is not visible).

[image]

Comment: Can you plz show me on my demo model (file attach). Whats the problem with that

Comment: this is your model  ;)

Comment: Thanks got it..

Comment: if you want to keep it non-destructive you need to find another way to create your object